# default ng-disabled else show another button

Tags: angularjs

I am kinda new to Angularjs . I have implemented the below .

```
<textarea ng-model='message' name='input_message'> 

<input type='button' name="sub_message" class='submit-btn' ng-disabled='!message' />
```

The above works fine . What it does is disables the button until something has been input in the textarea above . What i want to achieve is that by default it should show another button like below :

```
<input type='button' name="like_message" class='submit-btn' />
```

But if someone starts to enter some input in the textarea , the below button should be active again .

```
<input type='button' name="sub_message" class='submit-btn' ng-disabled='!message' />
```

Comment: so the button should be active by default but as soon as someone has entered something it should react with `ng-disabled`?

Comment: @AntiHeadshot - absolutely

Comment: do you want default settings for ngDisabled ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this your targetet behaviour

```
<textarea ng-model='message' ng-change="initialstate=false" ng-init="initialstate = true">
</textarea>

<input type='button' name="sub_message" value="submit" ng-if="message" />
<input type='button' name="like_message" value="like" ng-if="!message" />
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RVq6O3?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a ton . It worked . The only small issue that arises is that by default the like_message is active and if i type something the other button gets activated as desired .But if i type something and erase it , the default button does not come back .

Comment: I thaught this was the behavioutr you wanted XD. Give me a sec

Comment: @user1411837 is this solution helping? If so please accept it, else tell me wats wrong an I'll try to help.

Comment: no , its not something new...the solution is working but after i erase the input from the textarea , the like button should be displayed again . Logically speaking

Comment: @user1411837 I changed the code so it should do that about 2 hours ago ;P

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question, but it sounds like you want another button to appear as soon as the other one becomes active: that's a [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) if I ever saw one!

```
<input type='button' ng-if="message" name="like_message" class='submit-btn' />
```